# Available values font-weight for each font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am working on something like text editor using Google fonts and I want to build selector for font-weight, but I need only available values for font (for example Open Sans has 300, 400, 600, 700, 800), and so for everyone.

How can I get list of available values font-weight for each font?

Comment: This is a really long shot since you haven't been around since posting your question, but what language are you using to build this tool?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<select>` tag to input font-weight values.

here how you can do this.

you can use javascript code to add options of font-weight in `<select>` when a user selects a font-family

### CODE

---

**HTML**

```
<select id="font-family">
    <option value="'Times New Roman', Times, serif">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif">Impact</option>
    <option value="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Arial</option>
</select>
<select id="font-weight"></select>
```

---

JavaScript

```
var fntwgts = { 'FW_NewTimes': [100, 200, 300], 'FW_Arial': [300, 500, 600], 'FW_Impact': [200, 500, 700] };

document.getElementById('font-family').addEventListener("change", () => {
    var FW = document.getElementById('font-weight');
    if(FW.children.length>0){
        FW.innerHTML = '<option value="Default">Default</option>';
    }
    var val = document.getElementById('font-family').value;
    for (var i = 0; i < fntwgts[val].length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.setAttribute("value", fntwgts[val][i].toString());
        opt.innerHTML = fntwgts[val][i];
        FW.appendChild(opt);
    }
});
```